# how to replace a full view with another div using jquery

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, html

The view of a codeigniter page contain more than 1 page. 
1st page, has 3 div and a jquery function replaces last div using load(). Then in the subsequent view page i have remaining 2 div of 1st page and new div which i loaded now.

I need to replace the entire page with a new view. 
Somebody please help me.

Comment: The questions & whatever description you provided is too vague. Please support your question with some code

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you create template  with library and after call function with jquery post use load view this function

```
class template{

    public function __construct(){


    }

    var $main_template="template/template/theme";
    var $title="your title";


    public function loadview($template,$data)
    {

        $ci=& get_instance();

        $data["title"]==""  && $data["title"]=$this->title;

        $data["subject"]==""  && $data["subject"]=$this->title;

        $data["content"]=$ci->load->view($template,$data,true);
        if($data["side"]==1){
        $data["side"]=$ci->load->view('side',$data,true);
        }else
        {
            $data["side"]="";
        }

        $ci->load->view($this->main_template,$data);    

    }}
```

in controller:
    $this->template->loadview("file",$data);

and where user jquery post use:

```
$this->load->view("each",$data);
```